# variable scope related to while loop showing an error while accesing it after the while loop it is showing an err

Tags: java, loops, scope, initialization, declaration

```
import java.util.*;

public class gcd {
                
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
                 
        int n1 = scn.nextInt();
        int n2 = scn.nextInt();
        int rem;
        while(n1 % n2 != 0 ){
            r = n1 % n2;
            n1 = n2;
            n2 = rem;
        }
        System.out.println("gcd is :"+divisor);
        System.out.println(rem);
    }
}
```

I am declaring the `rem` variable outside the loop, initialising it in while loop and again accessing it after while loop. It is showing this error:

[image]

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: If the while-condition was immediately false, then `rem = dividend % divisor;` would not be executed, so `rem` would not have been initialised;

Comment: Now your code is mixing up `r` and `rem`, and does not make sense.

Comment: Plus divisor is never declared. Code for your question should be copied directly from your code.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the while loop might never be executed.  So initialization inside the loop might never happen.

Further, the compiler can't compute outcomes of the condition because it depends on unknown user input.

Initialize your variable `rem` at the declaration.